# How to only get the first 10 characters from a database field when querying with Eloquent Relationships?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

The situation: In the User's Profile, I am fetching all of the user's posts.

A post consists of a database field called "body" which is like the text in a blog article.

I only want to get the first 10 characters of the "body". Currently the code below gets the entire body which will be wasteful because I only need the first 10 characters.

```
public function show(User $user) 
{
    // This fetches all of the user's posts. Also it gets the entire body, which I don't want. I only want 10 characters from the "body".
    $posts = $user->posts;

    return view('users.user', compact('user', 'posts'));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Adjust your `posts` relationship (or add a separate one):

```
public function posts() {
    return $this->hasMany(...)
        ->select('id', 'user_id') /* all columns except "body" */
        ->selectRaw('SUBSTRING(`body`, 1, 10) as `body`');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So posts is an array of posts.  One option (though there are better ones) is to do this after your $posts = $user->posts;.

```
 foreach ($posts as $post){
       $teaser[] = substr($post, 0, 10);
    } 

    dd($teaser);
```

0 is the position you want to start and 10 is how many characters you want to display.  So if each post starts with " and you don't want that then you could put 1 instead of 0.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [Helper function](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/helpers) str_limit.

`str_limit($value, $limit = 100, $end = '...')`

`$value = str_limit('The PHP framework for web artisans.', 7);`

Answer (score -3):

If you want to show the first 10 characters then you can use the below code

```
$allUsers = User::paginate(10);
```

or you can use

```
$allUsers = User::take(10)->get();
```

Comment: characters as in letters from a string field. This would return the first 10 records